# How would i align my image above everything else on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm trying to get this image, which will end up being a logo, to appear above the table. Everything i have tried has just moved the image beside the other content rather than above it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 
</head>

<body>


  
    <style>
        main {
    
  background-color: #1e1f1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myInput {

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
     text-align: center;
    
}
#myInput:focus {
  outline:none;
     text-align: center;
}
header label {
  display:block;
     text-align: center;
}
header strong {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
    
  
}

main>div>div,
header div {
  padding: 15px 18px;
  background: white;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}

main>div>div {
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

main>div>div>strong {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10em;
}
output::before {
  content: '£';
}
output::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<body>
    <main>
  <header>
      <a href="https://www.ineedawheelchair.co.uk/"target="_blank"><img src="../Documents/RMS Logo - Oval.png" width="300" height="175" align="centre"></a>
    
      <label>
      <strong>Enter NHS Price Below</strong>
        <div>
          <input id="myInput"/>
        </div>
    </label>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div>
      <strong>Retail:</strong>
      <output id="output1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Schools &amp; CDC's:</strong>
      <output id="output2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band A:</strong>
      <output id="output3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band B:</strong>
      <output id="output4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band C:</strong>
      <output id="output5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band D:</strong>
      <output id="output6" />
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt) {
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3'), byId('output4'), byId('output5'), byId('output6')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    outputs[0].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7);
    outputs[1].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[2].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 40));
    outputs[3].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[4].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 20));
    outputs[5].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 10));
  } else {
    outputs[0].textContent =
      outputs[1].textContent =
      outputs[2].textContent =
      outputs[3].textContent =
      outputs[4].textContent =
      outputs[5].textContent = "*Please Enter a Number*";
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried aligning it to "top" and i cant find anything that makes it appear above, what would be the best and most simple way for me to move this image above?

Comment: why did you added img tag outside the body tag ?

Comment: @MetropolisCZ the edit didnt change it when you go onto full screen, it still appears to the side, is there a reason?

Comment: It is code snippet which can be run by us. It is better then pure code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML structure is wrong. The image shouldn't be inside the `<head>` tags. The head tag should be used for loading scripts for example. The `<header>` should not be repeated. I suggest to start by learning the basics of HTML structure here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

That said, I've moved the image outside the head. I've placed the image inside the `<header>`. If you want to center the image, make the header 100% width, then apply `display: block;` to your image and `margin: auto;`.

See example below.

```js
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt) {
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3'), byId('output4'), byId('output5'), byId('output6')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    outputs[0].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7);
    outputs[1].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[2].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 40));
    outputs[3].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[4].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 20));
    outputs[5].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 10));
  } else {
    outputs[0].textContent =
      outputs[1].textContent =
      outputs[2].textContent =
      outputs[3].textContent =
      outputs[4].textContent =
      outputs[5].textContent = "*Please Enter a Number*";
  }
}
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
}

header img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: #1e1f1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#myInput {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
}

header label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

header strong {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

main>div>div,
header div {
  padding: 15px 18px;
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

main>div>div {
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

main>div>div>strong {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10em;
}

output::before {
  content: '£';
}

output::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <img src="../Documents/square.jpg" width="300" height="175" align="top">
    </header>
    <div>
      <div>
        <strong>Enter NHS Price Below</strong>
        <input id="myInput" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Retail:</strong>
        <output id="output1" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Schools &amp; CDC's:</strong>
        <output id="output2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Trade - Band A:</strong>
        <output id="output3" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Trade - Band B:</strong>
        <output id="output4" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Trade - Band C:</strong>
        <output id="output5" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <strong>Trade - Band D:</strong>
        <output id="output6" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place it within your header tag but before the label

```
   <header>
    <img src="../Documents/square.jpg" width="300" height="175" align="top" >
    <label>
      <strong>Enter NHS Price Below</strong>
        <div>
          <input id="myInput"/>
        </div>
    </label>
  </header>
```

you can also place it before the main tag which might be a bad practice though you might need to create a menu/nav-bar containing the image link

```
   <nav>
      <img src="../Documents/square.jpg" width="300" height="175" align="top" >
   </nav>
```

Comment: Ah this worked, is there any way to make the image align central with the text?

Answer (score 0):

> I removed the image and create a class called image-top and added backgroud image their . Is this the thing are u asking about?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <img class="image-t" src="../Documents/square.jpg" width="300" height="175" align="top" > -->


   </head>
    <style>
        main {
    
  background-color: #1e1f1f;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.image-top{
    height: 50vh;
    background-image: url('https://www.hackingwithswift.com/uploads/matrix.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
#myInput {

  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
     text-align: center;
    
}
#myInput:focus {
  outline:none;
     text-align: center;
}
header label {
  display:block;
     text-align: center;
}
header strong {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
    
  
}

main>div>div,
header div {
  padding: 15px 18px;
  background: white;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
}

main>div>div {
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 15px 8px;
}

main>div>div>strong {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

output {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 10em;
}
output::before {
  content: '£';
}
output::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<body>
    <div class="image-top">
<p>img</p>
    </div>
    <main>
  <header>
    <label>
      <strong>Enter NHS Price Below</strong>
        <div>
          <input id="myInput"/>
        </div>
    </label>
  </header>
  <div>
    <div>
      <strong>Retail:</strong>
      <output id="output1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Schools &amp; CDC's:</strong>
      <output id="output2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band A:</strong>
      <output id="output3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band B:</strong>
      <output id="output4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band C:</strong>
      <output id="output5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <strong>Trade - Band D:</strong>
      <output id="output6" />
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt) {
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3'), byId('output4'), byId('output5'), byId('output6')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    outputs[0].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7);
    outputs[1].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[2].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 40));
    outputs[3].textContent = Math.ceil(value * 1);
    outputs[4].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 20));
    outputs[5].textContent = Math.ceil(value / 0.7 - (value / 0.7 / 100 * 10));
  } else {
    outputs[0].textContent =
      outputs[1].textContent =
      outputs[2].textContent =
      outputs[3].textContent =
      outputs[4].textContent =
      outputs[5].textContent = "*Please Enter a Number*";
  }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have done what i wanted to do, i just need to centre it

Comment: I just edited the code, if you take a look and maybe give me some input on how to align it to centre with the text?

Comment: @Lewis you can add `style="text-align: center;"` this to your `header` tag. It will align the image to the center

Answer (score -1):

To move something above something use `position: relative` or `position: absolute` and add `z-index` higher, than element after it.

E.g.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 10px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">

  <p>Text after image Text after image Text after image Text after image Text after image Text after image Text after image</p>

</body>

</html>
```

If that not your question, sorry, I did not correctly understand :)

Comment: I see, however its not just overlapping rather than going above,  im not sure if im doing something wrong?